# struts2 shopping cart multiple images for product

Tags: struts2

I wonder how can do multiple images uploading for shopping cart with struts2 
and when user want to add more or delete images what exactly i need to do

I have i dea

I have a add/edit product page in this page i have 2 tabs 1 for product information - 1 for images

after enter detail of product user click to tab images to add images for product.

in this images for product tab, user choose file from local to upload, upload with multiple images is not a problem but i wonder how to show it (i mean GUI) and user can delete images he  has been upload it mean image has been removed will be delete in local on hosting. and after that user click save to store image name into db

my problem is how to show multiple image and delete it? beside that in my action i use file[] fileupload and string[] filename to store images is it right?

Comment: that's right, just do it

Comment: i have a problem with showing i mean GUI bro!